# Mocha Unit Test with Jquery Submit

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm working on creating a Mocha unit test based on solution code that was given to me by someone else. (The goal here is to create an online code assessment for students that will be run against my unit test). It's a simple exercise and will not be extensible at all in the future.

I want to get the return value from a jQuery on-submit event and use that for my test case but am unsure how I can do that given the solution code that was given to me to work from.

I've gone through the document here (https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/867f76feea7cab4f8a84) but my particular case is different since we are using jQuery's on document ready and the on-submit.

I've also tried to do something like  "export.validate = function(){}" to match an example from the docs but everything I've tried I either get that Mocha doesn't know the function, or Mocha doesn't know the boolean variable references.

solutionCode.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form-submit").on("submit", function () {
      var xValid = true;
      var yValid = true;

      //...Bunch of logic here that could change the boolean values...

      return xValid && yValid;
  });
});
```

And here is my Mocha test file.js

```
this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')()
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var assert = require('assert');

var work = require('path/to/solutionCode.js');

describe('Validate Form', function() {
    it('Form is valid', function(done) {
        //Not sure how to get the return value here to do my assertion...
        done();
    });
});
```

If the value of both booleans in the return are True, the test should pass, otherwise it should fail.